# Pointer that can not be changed to a pointer that can not be written into?

Tags: c++, c

How to declare such a pointer?

Where shall I put the two `const`s?

I assume this it's the same in C and C++.

Comment: `int const** const`? (`const` pointer to a pointer to `const`)

Comment: qualifiers always apply to what's left of them. Unless they are on the far-left.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the four variations of `const`/non-`const` involving a pointer and the object it points to:

```
int i1 = 10;
const int i2 = 20;
int i3 = 30;
const int i4 = 40;

int* p1 = &i1;              // You can change p1 and *p1
*p1 = 25;                   // OK
p1 = &i3;                   // OK

const int* p2 = &i2;        // You can change p2 but not *p2
*p2 = 25;                   // Not OK
p2 = &i4;                   // OK

int* const p3 = &i1;        // You can not change p3 but you can change *p3
*p3 = 25;                   // OK
p3 = &i3;                   // Not OK

const int* const p4 = &i2;  // You can change neither p4 nor *p4
*p4 = 25;                   // Not OK
p4 = &i4;                   // Not OK
```

Comment: The question is about a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: @ouah, I didn't get that impression but I might be mistaken.

Comment: Title of the question is *Pointer that can not be changed to a pointer that can not be written into?*

Answer (score 0):

`const int * const ptr` will work.

The far left `const` apply to the int (the pointee) and the other `const` apply to what's a its left, `*`, aka the pointer.

```
int main()
{
  int i = 42;
  int b = 0;
  const int *const ptr = &i;

  ptr = &b; // doesn't compile
  *ptr = 1; // dito
}
```

Comment: The question is about a pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef const int *pointer_that_cannot_be_written_through;
typedef pointer_that_cannot_be_written_through *const unwriteable_pointer;
int a;
pointer_that_cannot_be_written_through b = &a;
unwriteable_pointer p = &b, q = &b;
p = q;    // ERROR
*p = *q;  // FINE
**p = **q // ERROR
```

In fact, the type of `p` is `const int **const`.