# Why I cannot use a top and low-level object to initialize another top-level?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants

I was studying about *const qualifier* with the book C++ Primer by Stanley B. Lippman but when I read about top-level and low level consts I got confused in the part where it envolves pointers.

***For example:***

In this part of the code

```
const int ci = 42; //ok
const int *p2 = &ci; //ok
const int *const p3 = p2; //ok
int *p = p3; //error
p2 = p3; //ok
```

I understand that `p3` has both, top-level and low-level const, because the object itself is const and the pointer can point to a const object.

**I don't understand correctly why top-level consts are ignored and why I can assign `p3` to `p2` but I cannot use `p3` to initialize `p`.** Can anyone explain me, with more details, the reason why it happens?

**PS:** I already saw [What are top-level const qualifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914444/what-are-top-level-const-qualifiers) question and it didn't help me that much.

Comment: Think of it this way: can you write to `*p2`? No, its const-ness prevents that, so the unwriteable `*p3` remains safe. But you *can* assign something to `*p`, which would write to `*p3`. Not allowed.

Comment: `p2 = p3;` is harmless because you can't use `p2` to modify either `p3` or `ci`; const-correctness is preserved. On the other hand, if `int *p = p3;` were allowed, then you could do `*p = 84;` which would modify `ci`, thus violating const-correctness.

Comment: [One of my answers to another SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28355561/434551) might be helpful.

Comment: @RSahu thank you for the sugestion, I will take a look!

Comment: @IgorTandetnik so we should always think about the future consequences, because even if I didn't change the value right now it can cause me future problems, right?

Comment: I think the names top-level and bottom-level are slightly confusing. The advice I can give you is look at the types to which the pointers point. If they match, you can assign them. If they don't, you can't. `p2` and `p3` are both pointers to `const int`, so you can assign `p3` to `p2`. `p` is a pointer to `int`, so you cannot assign it to either `p2` or `p3`. Note that you also cannot assign `p2` to `p3` (beyond initialization) because `p3` is a constant pointer. More precisely, it's a constant variable of type `pointer to const int`.

Comment: Not so much about future consequences, but about potential consequences - as in, "once I get this variable, what could I do with it?" The type system is designed in such a way as to prevent even a possibility of modifying a const value (unless you subvert it, e.g. with a cast, of course).

Comment: @HaithamGad It's not as simple as "types must match". You can go in the other direction - assign a pointer-to-non-const to pointer-to-const. The exact rules are spelled out in **[conv.qual]** and are pretty elaborate.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik ok, sure. I think I got it, thank you for the explanation and also to complement the answer made by Haitham, that could cause a very  confusing situation.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik sadly I cannot even ask you to send your comment as an answer because for some reason my question was marked as a duplicate. I'm sorry for that but thank you for the help.